# Clue is in the hint, What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> Everything can be a hint
>
> I am no longer the artist I once was
>
> But I still charge for my works
>
> I can kill slowly
>
> I can kill quickly
>
> I can be winning
>
> I can be showing the way

Hint:

> Clue

Comment: Clue really is in the hint

Comment: @Maria Deleva Нямаш спиране!

Comment: @RadoslavHristov, I am sorry if I am overstepping some boundaries.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Just kidding! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the answer? Forgive me this is my first post

> lead

Everything can be a hint

> a lead in a crime

I am no longer the artist I once was

> lead no longer used in paint

But I still charge for my works

> lead batteries

I can kill slowly

> lead poisoning

I can kill quickly

> lead bullets, thank-you Beastly Gerbil and M Oehm

I can be winning

> leading a race

I can be showing the way

> leading somebody

Comment: To add to Kallyfudge's answer, the lead pipe is a weapon in the game Clue

Comment: I don't know how fast you can swing the lead pipe, but bullets, traditionally made of lead, are supersonic.

Comment: Only the kill quickly part is wrong. :)

Comment: @Kallyfudge try lead bullets for killing quickly